# How To Solve This Multiple Integral?

Tags: integration

I have to solve this integral: $$ \int_D \frac {4x 4y 4z}{x^2}dxdydz,
\quad \text{where} \quad D=\left\{(x, y,z)  \in \mathbb R^3 \mid x,z \in [1,e], \ 0\le y\le\sqrt{\ln z}\right\}$$

I started with $$ \int_1^e \int_0^{\sqrt{\ln z}} \int_1^e \frac {4x4y4z}{x^2}dxdydz $$

but I'm stuck and can't calculate the first integral right because its hard for me to integrate a quotient. It would be nice if you would show me the first step with an explantation so I can try to go on.

Comment: $\log z$ or $\ln z$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it
 $$\begin{align} 
     &  \int_1^e \int_0^{\sqrt{\ln z}} \int_1^e \frac {4x4y4z}{x^2}dx dy dz \\
= & \int_1^e\int_0^{\sqrt{\ln z}} \left( 64yz\ln x \right) _1^e dy dz\\
= & \int_1^e\int_0^{\sqrt{\ln z}} 64yz dy dz\\
= & \int_1^e (32zy^2)_0^{\sqrt{\ln z}} dz\\
= & \int_1^e 32z\ln z dz\\
= & 16\int_1^e \ln z dz^2\\
= & (16z^2\ln z)_1^e - 16\int_1^e z^2 d\ln z\\
= & 16e^2 - 16\int_1^e zdz\\
= & 16e^2 - (8z^2)_1^e\\
= & 16e^2 - 8e^2 + 8\\
= & 8(e^2+1)
\end{align}$$

Addition:
$$\begin{align}
   & \int_1^e 32z\ln z dz\\
= & \int_1^e 16\ln z\cdot 2zdz \\
= & \int_1^e 16\ln z\cdot dz^2 \\
= & 16\int_1^e \ln z\cdot dz^2
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 3):

Just separate $x$ and change the order of $y \ \& \ z$:

$$\int_D \frac{4x4y4z}{x^2}dx dy dz = 64 \left( \int_1^e\frac{1}{x}dx \right) \left( \int_0^1 \int_{e^{y^2}}^e yz dz dy \right) = \dots $$

For boundary of $z$, just inverse the inequality $y \leq \sqrt{\ln z}$.

Comment: one question, how do you come up with e^y^2 in the last integral?

Comment: @Eiden I add some clarification.